# Loop space of a category

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, loop-spaces, homotopy-theory

This seems like it should be a "standard" thing, and I think I remember even seeing it somewhere, but I can't remember where.

Let $C$ be a small category.  Is there a category $\Lambda C$ whose nerve (or classifying space) is a model for the free loop space of the nerve (or classifying space) of $C$?  Probably the objects of $\Lambda C$ should be something like zigzags of morphisms in $C$.  A reference would be the best thing to hear.

Comment: Limits in the category of categories exist, so why not take the equalizer of the two maps Fun([1], C) evaluating at 0 and 1? The nerve respects limits so at least you'll get a good looking simplicial set. If I recall May correctly, geometric realization preserves pullbacks... So this seems like a good candidate.

Comment: @Dylan: this category has wrong homotopy type in general. It is actually isomorphic to the category of functors from the monoid `$\mathbb{N}$` to `$C$`. If you take `$C$` to be a category with two objects and two parallel arrows between them, then `$C$` is homotopy equivalent to a circle, so its loop space should be countably infinite discrete (up to homotopy), but your construction gives a finite category.

Comment: I don't know whether this contains an answer or not:
http://books.google.com/books/about/Topological_2_categories_and_principal_t.html?id=G4krAAAAYAAJ
but it does have some connection I think.

Comment: @Bob: Well, I can't tell since Google books won't even let me read the table of contents.  The title doesn't make me hopeful, though.

Comment: @Mike: the abstract says that: A method for associating to each topological category G, a principal top cat BXG is discussed. The first step is to associate with each G, a top 2-cat XG. The second is to apply the classifying space functor B. It is shown that there is a homomorphism BXG->G, which when restricted to the morphism spaces is a htpy equivalence of spaces over Ob G x Ob G. The particular example BX\Gamma^0 is considered and is shown to act on the disjoint union of (BA)^n, where A is a permutative category.

Comment: Do you need a concrete model? The naive constructions will fail as was mentioned by Karlo Szumilo...essentially because the Thomason model structure on Cat is not a simplicial monoidal closed model category, but still you can use the derived internal hom in Cat (wich exists) Thomason model structure... The model that you obtain for $\Lambda C$ is very big. I don't know if you need more details.

Comment: @Bob: I don't see anything in the abstract you quoted which seems related to the question; can you explain why you think it has some connection?

Comment: @Fedotov: Yes, I do need a concrete model, otherwise I wouldn't have asked.  It's a good point that there must be _some_ such category, namely the loop space object in the Thomason model structure, but I would like something more concrete, such as something made out of zigzags in C.

Comment: Grothendieck has worked on catégories de chemins, see www.math.jussieu.fr/~maltsin/groth/Derivateursengl.html .

Comment: @Mathias, are you saying that there is an answer to this question buried in Grothendieck's work, or merely that it seems related?

Comment: In Sec. 4 of Ch. VII, he constructs the path category _Ch_(X). In Sec. 12, he uses an alternative construction _Ch_oo(X) to produce an "analogue of the Cartan-Serre formalism". In Sec. 13, he constructs an equivalence of _Ch_(X) and _Ch_oo(X), saying the former is better. On page 106, then the (co)cone of a morphism appears. Of course, it's still in the form of a "mathematical diary", but the constructions are there.

Comment: @Matthias: Okay, thanks, I'll have a look.  (If you posted an answer describing Grothendieck's definitions and his theorems about them, I would be able to accept it...)

Answer (score 6):

My French is not good enough to be sure about it, but it seems that this paper has the definition you are after.

Evrard, Marcel *Fibrations de petites catégories.* Bull. Soc. Math. France 103 (1975), no. 3, 241–265. ([Numdam](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=BSMF_1975__103__241_0))

Comment: It certainly has a likely-looking _definition_ of $\Lambda C$, but I can't find in it a statement of the theorem I want.  He asserts that the _homotopy groups_ of $\Lambda C$ are isomorphic to those of the nerve of $C$ (referring to his thesis, which is apparently not available online, for the proofs).  But I don't see the stronger statement I want, that the nerve of $\Lambda C$ is weak homotopy equivalent to the loop space of the nerve of $C$.

Comment: Thanks, though.  Maybe if I could get a copy of his thesis, it would be in there.

Answer (score 3):

I will try to answer the question. As I said in a comment, the Thomason model structure on $Cat$ is not simplicial model structure. Let $C$ be a small category, we will view it as a topological category. Denote by $C[C^{-1}]$ the topological category where we invert all maps of $C$ such that $C\rightarrow C[C^{-1}]$ is a cofibration of topological categories, then the coherent nerve $N_{\bullet}C\rightarrow N_{\bullet}C[C^{-1}]$ induces a weak equivalence of simplicial sets. Notice that $C[C^{-1}]$ is an infinity groupoid.

Let $C$ be a cofibrant topological category. The mapping space $map(C,D)$ in the model category of topological categories   is given by the (standard) nerve of the following $HOM(C,D)$ category :

$\underline{Objects}$ are topological functor $F:C^{op}\times D:\rightarrow Top$ such that for any $c\in C,$  $F(c)$ is equivalent to a representable functor $D(d,-)$ for some $d\in D$.

$\underline{Morphisms}$ in this category are natural transformation $H:F\rightarrow G$ such that $F(c,d)\rightarrow G(c,d)$ is a weak equivalence for all $c\in C$ and $d\in D$.

Let $S^{1}$ a simplicial model for a circle. Let $k: sSet\rightarrow sSet$ the cocontinues Joyal functor which take $\Delta^{n}$ to the nerve of the groupoid with $n+1$ objects and only one isomorphism between any two objects.

Recall that $\mathfrak{C}: sSet\rightarrow Cat_{\Delta}$ is the left quillen adjoint to the coherent $N_{\bullet}$ betwen the joyal model structre on $sSet$ and the Bergner model structure on $Cat_{\Delta}$

Now $k(S^{1})$ is a simplicial set, and the cofibrant topological category $|\mathfrak{C}[k(S^{1})]|$ is an infinity groupoid and its cohenrent nerve is equivalent to $S^{1}$.
The finial result is that $HOM(|\mathfrak{C}[k(S^{1})]|, C[C^{-1}])$ is a model for $\Lambda C$, since the nerve of $HOM(|\mathfrak{C}[k(S^{1})]|, C[C^{-1}])$ is equivalent to $ map(|\mathfrak{C}[k(S^{1})]|, C[C^{-1}])\sim Map(S^{1},N_{\bullet}C[C^{-1}])\sim Map(S^{1}, N_{\bullet} C)=\Lambda N_{\bullet}C$

N.B. The only point that I did not explained is the construction of $C[C^{-1}]$. 
Let 1 be the category with two objets a and b and a unique morphisms from $: f:a\rightarrow b$. Let $\widehat{1}=|\mathfrak{C}[k(\Delta^{1})]|$, then $ C[C^{-1}]$ is the pushout 
$colim (\sqcup_{mor C} \widehat{1}\leftarrow \sqcup_{mor C} 1\rightarrow C  )$ i.e., for each porphism of $C$ there is a map $1\rightarrow C$.

Comment: But the construction of $C[C^{-1}]$ seems to be where a lot of the meat lies... that's where there'll be zigzags and stuff.  Also, this is not really concrete enough for what I want; too many geometric realizations and coherent nerves of very large categories.

Comment: I put the construction of $C[C^{-1}]$, it does not require zig-zags and it conceptually very easy. I agree that the constructed $\Lambda C$ is not very concrete but still you have a general model for the cotensorisation functor in $Cat$ (with Thomason model structure)  by $\sSet$.  

Comment: Computing pushouts of categories is not what I would call "easy"; that's where the zigzags are going to come in.